# Remotely shutdown a Windows machine

Tags: windows, shutdown

How can I shutdown or restart a Windows machine over remotely?

- It should handle many computer(thread)
- Ability to shutdown all computer or only one
- Work client/server...

Comment: without writing a client this is impossible. With writing a client this is quite easy to do, so I take it you want to do it clientless.

Comment: What do you mean by "computer(thread)"?  Do you also need a way to kill a particular process instead of shutting down the whole OS?

Comment: Mike Samuel, no i mean that it should handle many computers, i'm doing something like "Cyber Managment software" and i need a method to shutdown the "clients" computer or an especified computer, it's working with client-server

Comment: @11684 i want to do it server-client :)

Comment: then, is the question "how do I shut down the client machine once my client receives the shutdown command", or "how do I communicate with my client to tell it to shutdown"? @Takami

Comment: The second one "how do I communicate with my client to tell it to shutdown"?... @11684
Thanks in Advance :D

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`shutdown`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317371) command:

```
shutdown /s /m \\computername
shutdown /r /m \\computername
```

The `/s` switch is used for shutdown, `/r` for restart.

The full usage for shutdown on my Windows 7 box:

```
>shutdown /?
Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e] [/f]
    [/m \\computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

    No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
    /?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
    /i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
               This must be the first option.
    /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
    /s         Shutdown the computer.
    /r         Shutdown and restart the computer.
    /g         Shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
               rebooted, restart any registered applications.
    /a         Abort a system shutdown.
               This can only be used during the time-out period.
    /p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
               Can be used with /d and /f options.
    /h         Hibernate the local computer.
               Can be used with the /f option.
    /e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
    /m \\computer Specify the target computer.
    /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
               The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
               If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
               implied.
    /c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
    /f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
               The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
               specified for the /t parameter.
    /d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
               u indicates that the reason is user defined.
               If neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is
               unplanned.
               xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
               yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).
```

Comment: how can i detect if my computer was shut down remotely ?

Answer (score 0):

For Remote PC with in network run cmd is

shutdown -m \192.***.***.** -r -f -t 0
Where -m denotes for remote
 1. "-r" denotes restart the remote computer.
 2. "-f" flags tell the remote computer to restart and safely close all open programs.
 3. "-t" flag denote time after -t i.e here 0 sec.